# How to config correct OpenTelemetry Collector to Sky walking

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, skywalking

i try config OpenTelemetry Collector like this link: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-apache-skywalking-apm-tool-on-linux/?expand_article=1&expand_article=1&expand_article=1&expand_article=1
config like step 6.

After that, when i run cmd: systemctl status otelcol
all time result it's: active failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijxyM.png)
somebody know about it. Help me please?
thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.